# How to add duplicate pandas columns into one as list?

Tags: pandas, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns with same name. Is there a way to merge the duplicates into a single column, and all the values as list?

I want to merge these columns into one and take their values as a list.
[This is how dataframe looks like]
[image]

I apologize if it is a repetitive question, I couldn`t find the solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following worked for me.

```
df_combined = df.groupby(df.columns.values, axis=1).agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
```

All columns are named unique and their values are lists. [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO3cV.jpg) looks like this now. [Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XP6h.jpg) are now list of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a new column with all the 'responsible' together you can do this.

```
df['Resonsible list'] = df["Responsible.0"].map(str) + df["Responsible.2"].map(str) + df["Responsible.3"].map(str) + df["Responsible.4"].map(str) + df["Responsible.5"].map(str) + df["Responsible.6"].map(str)
```

if you want to add a comma inbetween them you can use some normal python code like this first

```
for x in df.columns:
    if Responsible in x:
        df[x] =  df[x].map(str) +", "
```

Please let me know if this is what you're asking.

Comment: It did not work, however I have found the solution.